# csh \ which $SHELL still gives /bin/bash

Tags: 10.04

I need to switch to c-shell and after installing it via software-center
it looks like I am ready to go.

Nevertheless, when I type 'csh' the line changes to %_
I am still not in a c-shell. When typing 
which $SHELL 
I get /bin/bash

Also my program is recognizing I am wrong and gives me error messages. 
I guess there is a simple solution?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

The SHELL environment variable does not indicate what shell you are currently using. It is simply set, when you log in, to the value of the login shell field of `/etc/passwd`, which in your case is `/bin/bash`.

If you want to change your login shell, run `chsh` (**ch**ange **sh**ell).

The login shell set in `/etc/passwd` controls, among other things, what shell is run when you open a terminal emulator, such as gnome-terminal.

To see what shell you are currently using, try `ps -p $$`

Comment: thanks!

Indeed, I am running csh after typing csh... clear.

But, I don't know why I have a strange behavior within the shell? I do not have tab completion... And my software is complaining that this might not be a c-shell (and therefore I can't install). Are there some options that I can activate?

thanks again!

Comment: @Hydrazin The shell from the csh package does not have tab-completion. tcsh does though, so maybe you want that instead. However, if all you want is to run a csh script, you do not need to run csh as an interactive shell at all. From any shell, just run  `csh scriptfile`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your default login shell and there many ways to do this. The command to change shells is -->   chsh -s csh  <-- will change your login shell to csh. After this it will be nessesary to logout and login to your account. -->  Ctl-d  <-- is for logout.

Also, you can check out all of the users login shells in the /etc/passwd file. It is the last field in the record and should be /bin/bash now. Be very careful in this file however! Incorrect settings will prevent user login!

Comment: thanks for the respond!

after writing chsh -s csh I get the answer:
chsh: csh is an invalid shell

thanks kind of strange?

Comment: @Hydrazin The argument to `chsh -s`, the shell to be set, should be an absolute path, and must be listed in /etc/shells. `cat /etc/shells`

Answer (score 0):

To see what shell you are currently using, try `echo $0`